# Django Dependencies

Tags: django

I am new to python and django and I just wanna ask and wanna use the django-audiofield app and I am following a certain installation process in a site

https://django-audiofield.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

and in the installation  process there's install dependencies, Do i need to change my OS cause I just found out that debian is an os but i don't wanna change my OS is there anyway to use django-audiofield without installing the dependencies or is it necessary to install those??

Comment: In this case the OS-level dependencies are not optional. You have not said which OS you are using, which we'd need to know. If you're using Windows, it looks like there's an [unmerged pull request for Windows support](https://github.com/areski/django-audiofield/pull/24), which suggests to me that's not currently supported. In which case you would need to switch to a supported OS if this field is necessary for you.

Comment: I have install successfully the audiofield  and now i have another problem ... when I try to upload an audio an error will appear in the localhost

Comment: FileNotFoundError at /admin/audiofield/audiofile/add/
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: that is the error that will appear  upon running the site

Comment: I'd suggest creating a new question with all relevant information, including full stack trace and code. You should also add and accept an answer to this question first so someone who has the same problem and finds this can see your solution.